# Form controls not showing

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, user-interface, user-controls

I'm making a console application that shows a form. I created the form from scratch. When I run the program, the form shows, but the controls I added don't show.

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;

namespace form
{
    public class main
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.Run(new FrmLogin());
        }
    }

    public class FrmLogin : Form
    {
        public void Frm()
        {
            this.Size = new Size(400, 600);
            Button btn = new Button();
            btn.Text = "Something";
            btn.Size = new Size(10, 10);
            btn.Location = new Point(10, 10);
            btn.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.Controls.Add(btn);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "A console application that displays a form" is a Windows Forms application, not a console application.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, you can actually build a project that uses forms as a Console project.  I've done this on occasion for debugging purposes.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, it's really just a matter of setting a project's Output Type to "Console Application" in the project properties.  The only noticeable differences are that a Console window shows up in the background when you run it and that if you run it from the command line, it doesn't return until the application is exited.  I don't know whether the OP has done this, or if so, for what purpose.  Just saying it can be done, and fairly easily--maybe even on accident.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're never calling your `FrmLogin.Frm` method.  If you intend this to be a constructor, drop the `void` and rename it to `FrmLogin`, like so:

```
public FrmLogin()
{
    this.Size = new Size(400, 600);
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.Text = "Something";
    btn.Size = new Size(10, 10);
    btn.Location = new Point(10, 10);
    btn.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
    this.Controls.Add(btn);
}
```

If you want instead to call it from the constructor, add a constructor called `FrmLogin` and have it call `Frm`, like so:

```
public FrmLogin()
{
    Frm();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Open a new windows forms application and observe source codes from form.designer.cs and program.cs You will see where you have been mistaken.